# VB.NET - Fill DataGridView with Parameterized DataSet Query

Tags: vb.net, postgresql, datagridview, parameters, dataset

Visual Studio 2015

Context :
I need to create a form to search the database by giving input from TextBox. PostgreSQL.

Code:

```
Image_dbTableAdapter.Fill(Image_db_DataSet.image_db, searchBox.Text)
```

DataSet:

[image: DataSet]

Query :

[image]

Parameters :
[image: Parameters]

But when I execute it, I get the following error :

```
"Column myName not found"
```

Please Help. I'm stuck with this for the past 3 days.

Comment: I don't see a column called `myImage`? Is that definitely the error?

Comment: Thanks for pointing @Jinx88909. It is myName

Comment: All those quotes don't look right, in your SQL

Comment: ok so how must it be quoted ?

Comment: First, I have no experience of PostgreSQL so I might be wildly wrong; but as so far you have had no other suggestions - putting quotes around all the column and table names like that would be wrong in the other dialects of SQL that I am familiar with. You might have to put square brackets round [name] if it's a reserved word.

Comment: even using [] gives error :( Please somebody help

Comment: In the wizard, what happens if you enter SELECT * FROM image_db   ?  Then try SELECT * FROM image_db WHERE name = @myname. What error message do you get?